# Recognize test in-app purchase android

Tags: android, google-play

We have an appplication where we verify all in-app purchases with Google, to make sure they are valid. Valid purchases are inserted into our database for analysis.

The purchases made by QA are also verified by Google. Because of this we cannot differentiate between real and test purchases in our database.

Is there a way to recognize test purchases?

Answer (score -1):

The best answer is probably the one that does not help you; QA should not be done on production data or in a production environment. It should be done in a separate environment dedicated to testing.

In other words, your production db should no contain irrelevant data produced by QA.